# Angular RxJS: Make subscriber callbacks run in order

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

Problem: I have to fetch both configuration and data from the server. The data can be rendered only after the configuration is fetched and loaded.

How I want my problem solved: I want to fetch both at the same time, using Angular's `HttpClient`. However, the callback for configuration must be executed first.

Attempt 1: I tried `concat()` from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519645/how-to-make-one-observable-sequence-wait-for-another-to-complete-before-emitting):

```js
concat(
    this.fetchConfig().pipe(take(1)),
    this.fetchData().pipe(take(1))
).subscribe(val => {
    if (isConfig(val)) {
        // This must be executed before the below populate(val);
        // This one is slow, blocking, so it must be executed
        // as soon as possible.
        load(val);
    } else {
        // val is data
        populate(val);
    }
});
```

However, I don't think it accomplishes my goal. I think Observable is a lazy executor, it only executes if there's something `subscribe()` to it. `concat()` delays the subscription of the callback to `fetchData()`, which also delays the actual fetching of data from the server.

Attempt 2: Use `forkJoin()`: `forkJoin()` only emits once all Observable emitted. The fetching of configuration is usually faster, then I want to execute its callback as soon as possible, so when the data is ready, the configuration may already be fully loaded.

How can I achieve this? And, btw, how can I fix my callback? Have some code to determine if `val` is data or configuration is very very ugly.

Edit: I edit the code for more clarification. Basically, I overengineered it. A `forkJoin()` should be OK for my case, as `load(val)` is pretty fast. However, I still want to push this, by forcing `load(val)` to be slow (this is actually what I thought this morning), so it has to be executed as soon as possible AND before `populate(val)`.

Right now I'm thinking of making an Observable with it and do chaining.

Comment: Checkout the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945846/how-to-make-2-dependent-http-request-in-angular-2. You will need to use the switchMap from rxjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make 2 dependent http request in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945846/how-to-make-2-dependent-http-request-in-angular-2)

Comment: You only need switchMap if the second request needs the result of the first request otherwise you are unnecessarily waiting for the first request to complete before starting the second. Using a combine latest you can fire both requests at once

Comment: what does `load(val)` do? Is it a http-request or what?`

Comment: @AJT82 it loads my configurations :v There's some calculation, but it's fast. Yesterday I thought it had to be slow.

Comment: why not call `load()` first and then call `populate()` after that, if the order matters?

Answer (score 2):

Combine latest will emit once both requests have completed

```
combineLatest(
    this.getJConfig(),
    this.fetchData()
).subscribe(([config, data]) => {
  // Use config
  // Then use data
});
```

No need for a take one on a http request as the observable completes once the request has finished.

There is no need to worry about using config as soon as it has finished as the amount of time it takes JavaScript to process the response is insignificant compared to the amount of time the request takes to complete.

If you really want to preserve order I came up with this convoluted beast a while ago for someone else [RxJS: MergeMap with Preserving Input order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035163/rxjs-mergemap-with-preserving-input-order)

Comment: Yes I want to preserve order. If `fetchData()` completes first, the data will be loaded without any config.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not perfect RxJS but you could do...

```
const configFetch = this.fetchConfig().toPromise();
const dataFetch = this.fetchData().toPromise();
const config = await configFetch;
processConfig(config);
const data = await dataFetch;
processData(data);
```